# Swagger ApiModelProperty for value class

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger

I'm trying to use the [Swagger Play2 Module](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/tree/master/play-2.5/swagger-play2) to generate api docs for a Play application. We use a lot of value classes for some additional type-safety and code readability.

One of the actions generates JSON for a case class like the following:

```
case class MyResponse(prop1: MyValueType, prop2: MyValueType)
```

where `MyValueType` is such a value class:

```
case class MyValueType(value: String)
```

that is formatted to JSON just as a string using a custom `Format[T]`.

Swagger UI generates example JSON code like this:

```
{
  "prop1": {
      "value": "string"
  },
  "prop2": {
      "value": "string"
  }
}
```

while I would like it to generate this:

```
{
  "prop1": "string",
  "prop2": "string"
}
```

I have tried a custom annotation like this, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
case class MyResponse(
  @ApiModelProperty(dataType="string") prop1: MyValueType, 
  @ApiModelProperty(dataType="string") prop2: MyValueType, 
)
```

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What doesn't work when you try this? Could you describe the error?

Answer (score 2):

Try dataType="String" with a capital

Answer (score 0):

Swagger is wrapping your `case class MyValueType` within your `case class MyResponse`.

It is ignoring your `dataType` annotation, and still parsing `MyValueType`

Did you try with a more complete annotation of your properties? Something like:

```
case class MyResponse(@ApiModelProperty(
                          value = "Property 1",
                          dataType="string") prop1: MyValueType, 
                      @ApiModelProperty(
                          value = "Property 2",
                          dataType="string") prop2: MyValueType)
```

By the way, the data types in Swagger are not case sensitive, therefore `string` is equivalent to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried `@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "String")` and `@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string")`. Neither of them works.

However, `@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "java.lang.String")` works in my case.

My springfox version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```